# update find results in one statemet using pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a function like this:

```
def max_number(list_):
    dict_ = {
     "a": 1,
     "b": 2,
     "c": 3,
     "d": 4
    }
    list_ = [dict_[i] for i in list_]
    return max(list_)
```

and `db.test.find()` returns:

```
{"name": "name1", "level": ["a", "d"]}
{"name": "name2", "level": ["c"]}
{"name": "name3", "level": ["a", "c"]}
```

Now I want to get max level in every record by using function `max_number`, the result after update should looks like:

```
{"name": "name1", "level": ["a", "d"], "max": 4}
{"name": "name2", "level": ["c"], "max": 3}
{"name": "name3", "level": ["a", "c"], "max": 3}
```

I know I can use `find()` and then update it one by one using a for loop.
But I wonder if there is a method that can help me finish this task in one statement, as if I have a large collect, it might be quite slow to do this task with a for loop.

The statement may look like:

```
db.test.update_many({}, {"$set": {"max": max_number(result.level)}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information you mentioned in the question .Below solution could do the job.

```
cursor_list=list(db.test.find())
# cursor_list=[{"name": "name1", "level": ["a", "d"]},{"name": "name2", "level": ["c"]},{"name": "name3", "level": ["a", "c"]}]
value_l=[d["level"] for d in cursor_list]
# value_l=[['a', 'd'], ['c'], ['a', 'c']]

name_l=[d["name"] for d in cursor_list]

dict_ = {
     "a": 1,
     "b": 2,
     "c": 3,
     "d": 4
    }

def replace_matched_items(word_list, dictionary):
"""maps the value in sublist to the dict values"""

    new_list = [[dictionary.get(item, item) for item in lst] for lst in word_list]
    return new_list

list_ = replace_matched_items(value_l, dict_)
# list_=[[1, 4], [3], [1, 3]]
max_value=[max(l) for l in list_]
# max_value=[4, 3, 3]
# it updates to the field "max" wrt to the "name" field which I supposed is unique
for i in range(len(value_l)):
    db.test.update({"name": name_l[i]}, {"$set": {"max": max_value[i]}})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  May be I did not express myself clearly，I edit the question, chang `update` to `update_many`.  Time efficiency is what I care about most.  My `cursor_list ` can be a quit big list, will it take too long while using update one by one in a for loop? Is there a solution that can solve this problem with `update_many`?

Comment: do you want to do some kind of processing on this data later? or just want to add a field in db itself?

Comment: just add a field to the document, but the value of the field comes from the document it self.

Comment: @幽幽子的筷子 please accept the answer if it was useful so that others can make out that you are satisified with the answer